# How to add more amount of projects in Xcode Welcome Window

Tags: xcode

My Xcode only can show about 5 amount in the Recently Projects Window.

How to add more items? I can't find any setting in Xcode Preference.

Thanks a lot!

[image: Xcode Welcome Window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use File > Open Recent instead. It can show a *lot* of recent projects.

Comment: No one uses the welcome window for anything. Uncheck "Show this window when Xcode launches".

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. My "File > Open Recent instead" also has 5 items too...

Comment: System Preferences > General > Recent Items